# Is the following set closed in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the following set

> $S=${$(x,y):0<x<1;y=(\sin x)/x$} is closed in $\mathbb R^2$?

Problem is that Closed graph theorem (from Munkres page 171, Ex 8) makes the confusion about closedness. I will appreciate the answer which clearly points out the fallacy, not merely stating it is not closed as limit point not in the set.

Comment: Is it closed and bounded?

Comment: Problem is about closedness... by closed graph theorem it should be closed as the function is continuous.... but is not (1,sin1) is a limit point of the set which is not in the set.. confused.

Comment: If there's a limit point not in the set, then it's not closed.

Comment: closed Graph theorem says : Let, f : X-->Y ; Let Y be compact Hausdroff. Then, f is Continuous iff the graph of f [ defn of Graph of a function : G_f := {x X f(x) | x€X} ] is Closed in X x Y.

Comment: and  I think sinx/x is continuous on (0,1).

Comment: so can you help what mistake I am doing here??

Comment: As $f : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$, the codomain is not compact so the theorem you refer to does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not, as $(0,1)$ is a limit point of $S$ and $(0,1)\not\in S$.

It is a limit point since
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{\sin\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\in S,
$$
and
$$
\frac{\sin\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)}{\frac{1}{n}}=n\sin\big(\tfrac{1}{n}\big)\to 1,
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: What about  
closed Graph theorem ?

Comment: @user123804: What is shown above is exactly the the graph of this function is NOT closed.

Comment: are you saying sinx/x is not continuous on(0,1) or the stated them is wrong?

Comment: I very much agree with the fact that the limit point not belongs to the set but wanting to relate the idea with the theorem... The set should not be closed...What is the fallacy?

Comment: The Closed Graph Theorem says that if the graph is closed, then the map is continuous (for Banach spaces). $X=(0,1)$ is not a complete space, and hence this theorem does not apply!

Comment: please check munkres page no 171 exercise no 8. the statement is exactly the same

Comment: @user123804: According to this exercise, if $Y$ is compact and $G_f$ is closed in $X\times Y$, then $f$ is continuous. Nevertheless, $f$ can be continuous, while its graph not being closed (i.e., $f:(0,1)\to(0,1)$, with $f(x)=x$.). But here WE KNOW that $f$ is continuous anyway, so  where is the problem?